# If $\boldsymbol{I} = (I_1, \ldots, I_n)$ is a are indicator random variables where $P(I_j = 1) = p$, how to find $E\left(\sum_{j:I_j=1}I_j\right)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $\boldsymbol{I} = (I_1, \ldots, I_n)$ is a sequence of independent indicator random variables where $P(I_j = 1) = p$. Now, defined $N_1$ and $N_0$ to be:

$$
N_1 = \sum_{j:I_j=1}I_j
$$

and

$$
N_0 = \sum_{j:I_j=0}I_j
$$

Then, we have that $N_0 = n-N_1$. I would like to find $E[N_1]$ and $E[N_0]$. It seems they should be $np$ and $n(1-p)$, but I am not sure how to get it. I have tried to use: $E(N_1) = E(E(N_1|\boldsymbol{I})$, but to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $N_1 = \sum_k I_k$, so $E N_1 = \sum_k E I_k = np$.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how you got the last equality. It seems that $N_1$ would be lesser or equal to $n$, so why are we sort of assuming the biggest case? Is there a way to think about it another way?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Note that $I_k$ only takes values  $\{0,1\}$, so $N_1 = \sum_k I_k = \sum_{k \in \{ i | I_i = 1 \}} I_k$. The expectation is linear, and you have provided that $P[I_j = 1] = p$, and $E I_k = 1\cdot P[I_j = 1] + 0 \cdot P[I_j = 0] = p$.

Comment: This is a good answer, and btw this whole question is just how Bernoulli random variables (Bernoulli trials) add up to a Binomial random variable.

Comment: @copper.hat My confusion is now you obtained the $n$. It appears to be that the $k$ go from $1$ to $n$. However, the second sum has the index $k \in \{ i | I_i = 1 \}$. Here, the set $\{ i | I_i = 1 \}$ appears to have cardinality less than $n$, so im not sure where the $n$ is coming from.

Comment: The sum is over **all** indices, since if $I_k = 0$ then adding $0$ to the sum changes nothing. Then $\sum_k E I_k = \sum_k p = np$. Note that $N_1,I_k$ are functions of some implicit variable, say $\omega$, hence you have $N_1(\omega) = \sum_{k} I_k (\omega)$. This is true for **all** $\omega$. The result then follows from linearity of expectation.

Comment: @copper.hat So basically the way I defined $N_1 = \sum_{\{ i | I_i = 1 \}} I_i$ above is not necessarily correct? Since the way I defined it above only sums through **certain** $i$?

Comment: @user321627: Not exactly. Since $I_i$ is either zero or one, summing over all indices is the same as summing over the indices for which $I_i = 1$. However, the computation of the expectation is simpler when you sum over all indices. Note that the $N_0$ above, as you have defined it, is **always** zero. You probably meant something like $N_0 = \sum_{j:I_j=0}1$, note that you could also have written $N_0 = \sum_k (1-I_k)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I see what you're saying now. You mention that the expectation is simpler summing over all indices. If I wanted to go the long way of doing it, would it then involve iterated exepctations? i.e. $E(N_1) = E(E(N_1|I))$?

Comment: @user321627: Yes, that is correct. I wasn't thinking of that originally, I was just being lazy :-).